# how to format contents of data frame using openxlsx::writedata

Tags: r, excel

I have used the below code to write data from R to excel. Style is implemented only for the header but not for the corresponding value. How to change the style as needed including the indentation, bold, and font size, etc;

```
h1=openxlsx::createStyle(fontSize = 12, fontColour = "#FFFFFF", halign = "center",
                         fgFill = "#4F81BD", border = "TopBottomLeftRight", borderColour = "#4F81BD", 
                         valign = "center", textDecoration = "bold",wrapText = FALSE)



openxlsx::writeData(wb1,'sheet1', df1,startCol = 4, startRow = 6,headerStyle =h1,borders="all", borderColour = "black",)
openxlsx::writeData(wb1,'sheet2', df2,startCol = 5, startRow = 6,headerStyle =h1,borders="all", borderColour = "black",)
```

[image: Existing Output]

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: The images have not uploaded.

Comment: Images uploaded, kindly suggest

Comment: Any suggestions for the above request?

Comment: Could you include a heading or explanation of what the images represent? Do you want the values in the rows below the header to be the same style as the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to find a solution by usinf justify command "data=format(data, width = name.width, justify = "centre")